# Error when Trying to import external framework to Xcode 9

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode9

I´m working on an app that integrates MySpin system from bosch, and there is a framework available to be used in the process.

I did all the importing process of the framework into my Xcode 9 project with a drag and drop into the frameworks project folder and linked to the target app.

[image: external framework importing]

But I´m not able to use the header file from the framework in my project.

I tried to import in some different ways, changing the options : Copy items if needed, Create Groups e Create folder references but the file dos not appear in the auto complete of importing process inside the `AppDelegate.h`, the error File not found always appears.

[image: Erro no arquivo AppDelegate.h]

also included the folder path to the Header Search Path option.

Does anyone had any ideia on how to solve this importing problem? I have all files inside a local folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check copy items if needed and add it to Embedded libraries , dynamic frameworks sections as below
[image]

Comment: Sh_Khan.  Can you explain why you have to Check Copy Items if Needed?  I've often wondered about that.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Sh_Khan, thanks for the help but id didn't work =(, still file not found error message (Clean and Build done)

Comment: @Martin Suppose framework is in Desktop and you dragged it to the project if you unchecked copy items it will not be copied to project folder and only a reference to it's path in the project , if the framework that is in desktop is deleted to you moved it anywhere project won't compile complaining framework not found , this is way check copy is useful

Comment: So the project will build regards of where the framework is.  But to properly manage the project you should have all your files in the project folder?  That makes sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: I got it working add the full path, including the the Headers folder, to the "Header Search Path", but is it a correct action to do?